# Submit Button opening PHP page and not sending data

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I have googled and googled this and followed a dozen tutorials and trouble shooting guides and can still not ge the submit button to work. It just opens the php page with no code show. I have run the  and it returns the info showing that PHP is installed on the server.

Please can someone help me out with the PHP code and let me know where I have messed up.

```
<form action="http://www.rexu.co.uk/email_submit.php" method="post">
          <input type="name" value="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
          <input type="email" value="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
          <input type="tel" value="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
          <textarea type="message" value="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" rows="6"></textarea>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" class="form-control" value="SEND EMAIL">
        </form>



    <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $to = 'myemail@mysite.com'; // changed for security reason. Have been using my acutal email address
     $subject = 'From Rexu Contact Form';
$message = 'name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= 'email: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= 'tel: ' . $_POST['tel'] . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= 'message: ' . $_POST['message'];
}
?>
```

Many Thanks

Comment: How do you know it's not sending the data?

Comment: You need to `echo` something to show in page. I don't see anything here. Just `echo $message` will show your message body.

Comment: Is this your site: http://www.rexu.co.uk/email_submit.php, or are you trying to send data to a remote server?

Comment: you're not echoing anything and not sending any mail here. All you did was define variables. Plus, there are no name attributes to match your POST arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You see a blank page, because you never echo any data.

Try `echo $message` at the end of your if-statement to see, if any data is sent.
Or add an `else` and output an error-message, if `isset($_POST['submit'])` is `false`

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to send an email, it seems you forgot to do it. You can use mail() function to achieve this.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $to = 'myemail@mysite.com'; // changed for security reason. Have been using my acutal email address
     $subject = 'From Rexu Contact Form';
$echo 'name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n\r\n";
$echo 'email: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n\r\n";
$echo 'tel: ' . $_POST['tel'] . "\r\n\r\n";
$echo 'message: ' . $_POST['message'];
}
?>
```

try this! Also in our HTML code, the form action... Is it pointing to the correct address check that as well.

Comment: Thank you all for your help on this. I manged to get the form sending by adding the $to, changing the contact page into a .php and have the success message show about the contact form.